# Java Issue with taking contents of a text file into an array and then displaying and manipulating the contents of the array

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

Okay so this is a school project and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I realize there are better ways to do a lot of this but it has to be done this way (I will note specifically what).

I need to write two very simple programs.

1. The first program creates a file of 300 random integers in the range of 1 to 54 and then there printed to a text file.
2. The second program reads that text file and takes the contents into an array. The array is then manipulated to output a few things, The average of the numbers, and how many times the numbers appear in a certain range. I'm also attempting to out put the entire array at once. Unfortunately all of part is basically not working, or I'm not understanding some thing and i'm quite sure it's both lol.

Program 1 Is as follows

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class OutStream{ 
public static void main(String[] args){
int Counter = 0,
    Value;
Random Gen = new Random();
System.out.println("Generating Numbers and Text File Now");
   try{
        File out = new File("F:\\Text.txt");
        PrintWriter P = new PrintWriter(out);
        while(Counter <= 300){
            Value = Gen.nextInt(54)+1;
            P.println(Value);
            ++Counter;
            System.out.println("Value: " + Value);
        } 
        P.close();
  }catch(Exception E){ 
  E.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(E.getMessage());
  } 
  System.out.println("The Program has ended");
 }   
}
```

The second Program is where it all breaks down.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class InStream {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int [] NumArray = new int[301];
int PosNum = 0,
    Total = 0,
    Average = 0,
    Range1 = 0,
    Range2 = 0,
    Range3 = 0,
    Range4 = 0,
    Range5 = 0,
    Range6 = 0;

    try{
        File Fout = new File("F:\\Text.txt");
        PosNum = 0;
        Scanner Fin = new Scanner(Fout);
        while(Fin.hasNextInt()){
            NumArray[++PosNum] = Fin.nextInt();


        }
        Fin.close();

       }catch(Exception E){
           E.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("***ERROR ***** " + E.getMessage());
       } 


for(NumArray[PosNum] = 0; NumArray[PosNum] <= 301;){
    Total += NumArray[PosNum++];

    if(NumArray[Range1] >= 1 && NumArray[Range1] <= 10){
       Range1++;
    }

    if (NumArray[Range2] >= 11 && NumArray[Range2] <= 20){
        Range2++;
    }
    if(NumArray[Range3] >= 21 && NumArray[Range3] <= 30){
       Range3++;
    }
    if(NumArray[Range4] >= 31 && NumArray[Range4] <= 40){
       Range4++;
    }
    if(NumArray[Range5] >= 41 && NumArray[Range5] <= 50){
       Range5++;
    }
    if(NumArray[Range6] >= 51 && NumArray[Range6] <= 54){
       Range6++;
    }  

}
Average = Total / 301;
System.out.println("The Average Is: " + Average);
System.out.println("1 Through 10 appear: " + Range1 + " Times");
System.out.println(" 11 Through 20 appear: " + Range2 + "Times");
System.out.println("21 Through 30 appear: " + Range3 + " Times");
System.out.println("31 Through 40 appear: " + Range4 + " Times");
System.out.println("41 Through 50 appear: " + Range5 + " Times");
System.out.println("51 Through 54 appear: " + Range6 + " Times");
 }

}
```

This is my newest attempt.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FixedInstream {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] MyArray = new int[301];
    int PosNum = 0,
        Average,
        Total = 0,
        R1 = 0,
        R2 = 0,
        R3 = 0,
        R4 = 0,
        R5 = 0,
        R6 = 0,
        R7 = 0;

    try{
        File Fout = new File("F:\\Text.txt");
        PosNum = 0;
        Scanner Fin = new Scanner(Fout);
        while(Fin.hasNextInt()){
            MyArray[PosNum] = Fin.nextInt();
            Total += MyArray[PosNum];
        }
        Fin.close();

    }catch(Exception E){
           E.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("***ERROR ***** " + E.getMessage());
       } 
    for(MyArray[PosNum] = 0; MyArray[PosNum] <= 300; ++MyArray[PosNum]){


        if(MyArray[R1] >= 1 && MyArray[R1] <= 10){
            R1++;
        }

        if (MyArray[R2] >= 11 && MyArray[R2] <= 20){
            R2++;
        }
        if(MyArray[R3] >= 21 && MyArray[R3] <= 30){
            R3++;
        }
        if(MyArray[R4] >= 31 && MyArray[R4] <= 40){
            R4++;
        }
        if(MyArray[R5] >= 41 && MyArray[R5] <= 50){
            R5++;
        }
        if(MyArray[R6] >= 51 && MyArray[R6] <= 54){
            R6++;
        }  
    }

    Average = Total / 301;
    System.out.println("The Average Is: " + Average);
    System.out.println("1 Through 10 appear: " + R1 + " Times");
    System.out.println("11 Through 20 appear: " + R2 + " Times");
    System.out.println("21 Through 30 appear: " + R3 + " Times");
    System.out.println("31 Through 40 appear: " + R4 + " Times");
    System.out.println("41 Through 50 appear: " + R5 + " Times");
    System.out.println("T51 Through 54 appear: " + R6 + " Times");
  }

}
```

The program is not out putting correctly Example below that I apparently forgot to add in my initial comment.

Output:

```
The Average Is: 27
The Numbers 1 Through 10 appear: 1 Times
The Numbers 11 Through 20 appear: 1 Times
The Numbers 21 Through 30 appear: 1 Times
The Numbers 31 Through 40 appear: 1 Times
The Numbers 41 Through 50 appear: 1 Times
The Numbers 51 Through 54 appear: 1 Times
```

There are 300 numbers in the text file 1 - 54  the numbers repeat differently but generally 10 - 50 times as you can see above from that out put it's only showing once, which leads me to believe I'm not increment some thing correctly.

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate what the exact problem is, inputs and expected outputs, and what work you've done to try to debug the problem.

Comment: I agree with @SkinnyJ you aren't being clear enough as to what exactly is happening. Also when you say it must be done this way in what way do you mean? There are much better ways to read and write those files including BufferedReaders and Writers as opposed to the Scanner class. Can you clarify?

Comment: I already did as stated above at the very top of the program and at the bottom of the source code. 1. I need to find the average number contained in the area. 2. I need to display the amount times the numbers 1- 10 11- 20 21 - 30 31 - 40 etc.. are repeated.  I'v tried many different things and I wont go over the mall because it's not relevant. I'll post the newest attempt in a momment

Comment: " It must be done in this way " That's pretty self explanatory, it's a school project which means the way I have this laid out is the way it has to be handed in. Obviously the errors have to be fixed and I'm attempting to do so. I'm not looking for you to re-write my source code I'm looking for a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a lot of confusing things here... Here below is the answer, but I would advise you to try debugging this snippet by yourself to learn what is wrong.

1. You're itering trough an array with `301` cells. An array index goes from `0` to `length-1`. As you're itering with `numArray[++posNum]` when posNum was initialized with 0, the first index will be `++0 = 1`. So you never reach the first cell of the array. This lead to an `out of range exception` because the last index will be `301` but in reality the last index is `300`... Simply reading the exception message would have lead you to the solution.
2. I would advise you to take a look at how works a `for loop` to understand how to browse the array cell by cell with an incremented index. Then you will correct your for loop like this :

   for(int idx = 0; idx < NumArray.length; idx++)
3. You were accessing the current cell with the wrong variable. This can append, but you would have detected it very fast in debug mode...

   NumArray[idx]

instead of

```
NumArray[Range1]
```

4. This is not essential to make your program work, but in Java there are some conventions (as in every langages) and `variables` are written in `camelCase`.

   public class InStream {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int [] NumArray = new int[301];
       int PosNum = 0,
           Total = 0,
           Average = 0,
           Range1 = 0,
           Range2 = 0,
           Range3 = 0,
           Range4 = 0,
           Range5 = 0,
           Range6 = 0;

       try{
           File Fout = new File("F:\\Text.txt");
           PosNum = 0;
           Scanner Fin = new Scanner(Fout);
           while(Fin.hasNextInt()){
               NumArray[PosNum++] = Fin.nextInt();
           }
           Fin.close();

       }catch(Exception E){
           E.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("***ERROR ***** " + E.getMessage());
       }


       for(int idx = 0; idx < NumArray.length; idx++){
           Total += NumArray[idx];

           if(NumArray[idx] >= 1 && NumArray[idx] <= 10){
               Range1++;
           }

           if (NumArray[idx] >= 11 && NumArray[idx] <= 20){
               Range2++;
           }
           if(NumArray[idx] >= 21 && NumArray[idx] <= 30){
               Range3++;
           }
           if(NumArray[idx] >= 31 && NumArray[idx] <= 40){
               Range4++;
           }
           if(NumArray[idx] >= 41 && NumArray[idx] <= 50){
               Range5++;
           }
           if(NumArray[idx] >= 51 && NumArray[idx] <= 54){
               Range6++;
           }
       }
       Average = Total / 301;
       System.out.println("The Average Is: " + Average);
       System.out.println(" 1 Through 10 appear: " + Range1 + " Times");
       System.out.println("11 Through 20 appear: " + Range2 + " Times");
       System.out.println("21 Through 30 appear: " + Range3 + " Times");
       System.out.println("31 Through 40 appear: " + Range4 + " Times");
       System.out.println("41 Through 50 appear: " + Range5 + " Times");
       System.out.println("51 Through 54 appear: " + Range6 + " Times");
   }
   ```

   }

Don't hesitate to debug your program, this is the best way to learn the langage, and enjoy Java

Comment: Thank you Miam84 I was getting very frustrated because my very first version looked like this with a few exceptions, for example I new of the .length() but I was under the impression it applied only to strings I was mistaken!  Also I'd like to point out that understanding the array out of bounds exception was clear and I did understand how to solve it I aslo stated I was in the process of re writing it. I was mainly having issues with pre and post fix incrementing java also requires a lot more then what I'm used to and I'm in the starting stages of learning it, it's only been a few days

Comment: Proud that it helped. Then now you're good to go further ;)As this answer solved your problem, you can set it as accepted with the checkmark. This will mark the problem as resolved